# Single node cluster installation permission errors

Tags: hadoop

command is bin/start-all.sh

hadoop@user-HP-dx2480-MT-NA125PA:/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop$ bin/start-all.sh

error are

```
mv: cannot move `/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop/bin/../logs/hadoop-hadoop-namenode-user-HP-dx2480-MT-NA125PA.out.4' to `/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop/bin/../logs/hadoop-hadoop-namenode-user-HP-dx2480-MT-NA125PA.out.5': Permission denied
mv: try to overwrite `/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop/bin/../logs/hadoop-hadoop-namenode-user-HP-dx2480-MT-NA125PA.out.4', overriding mode 0644 (rw-r--r--)? 
mv: try to overwrite `/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop/bin/../logs/hadoop-hadoop-namenode-user-HP-dx2480-MT-NA125PA.out.3', overriding mode 0644 (rw-r--r--)? 
mv: try to overwrite `/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop/bin/../logs/hadoop-hadoop-namenode-user-HP-dx2480-MT-NA125PA.out.2', overriding mode 0644 (rw-r--r--)?
```

any solution to this??

Comment: I have 2 suggestions: Check the permissions on the directory/files and see what they are set to. Also, Edit the proper XML file (not at work, don't have system to see which one) and remove the `..` from the log path (What is the log path set to?).   Once I get to work I'll dig out my docs and get into my hadoop install and see if I can give some better suggestions.

Comment: @ Nija :ok fine

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a permission issue. Try executing start-all with `sudo` command.

Answer (score 0):

1. Creating user

   ```
     sudo addgroup hadoop    
     sudo adduser --ingroup hadoop hduser
   ```
2. Add below line to add hduser into sudoers, `vi  /etc/sudoers`

   ```
    hduser (ALL)=(ALL) ALL
   ```
3. Change hadoop owner

   ```
    chown  -R hduser:hadoop hadoop
   ```

where `hduser` → username, `hadoop` → group name